# Using Russian English dictionary programmatically

Tags: dictionary, translation

I would be grateful if someone can help me.
Is there a way to use russian to english translation. (word per word, not sentences) 
I've heard and tried  google translate API, however I need the program to work with large amounts of words and not be tied to Internet connection. Maybe, some standalone dictionary.
I've found this dictionary : http://sdict.com/en/view.php?file=rus_eng_full2.dct and tried to apply dictconv linux utility to convert to plaintext, so I can use it, but it crashes and compiling it from source doesn't work.
Maybe, someone knows a way to read .dct format and have an open source solution for it or link to it. I haven't found.
If there's a reliable Internet based solution, I would also like to hear about it.
Thank you, world, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay using python download sdictviewer-lib from here
https://github.com/jmhobbs/sdictviewer-lib

And use following script to read

```
import sdictviewer.formats.dct.sdict as sdict
import sdictviewer.dictutil

dictionary = sdict.SDictionary( 'rus-eng.dct' )
dictionary.load()
dictionary.get_word_list_iter('russianword')
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get sdictviewer to load the aforementioned dictionary, if anyone has gotten this to work, let me know.